# How to make the value of the decimal only show in numerals?

Tags: c, floating-point, decimal

Im trying to make my c program run any value that you put in will come out as words for example if I wanted to put in the value 1234.56 it should come out as "One Thousand Two Hundred Thirty Four Dollars ... and 56 Cents" Notice how the cents are only in numerals. So far I have properly written the code that will be able to transfer the numbers to words but I have no clue how to only leave the part for the cents alone. Please help!!

Currently for the decimals I get some outrageous number in the negatives!

The code is as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printNum(int);
void printNum2(int);
void printNum3(int);
void printNum4(int);
int main()
{

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0, e=0;

    float inclusive;

    printf("Welcome to the IPC144 Cheque Generator!!\n");
    printf("PAY TO THE ORDER OF... amahmood29 (018359133)\n");
    printf("Enter a monetary value from $0.01 to $9999.99 inclusive: ");
    scanf("%f", &inclusive);

    if(inclusive < 0.01 || inclusive > 9999.99) {
           printf("Sorry, cannot create cheque for that amount, try again next time!\n");
             }
    else
    {                                             
        a = inclusive / 1000;                          //This data is replacing our variable by diving whatever the value is by either 1000, 100, 10.
        inclusive = inclusive - (a*1000);
        b = inclusive / 100; 
                inclusive = inclusive - (b*100);
        if ( inclusive > 19 )
        {
                    c = inclusive / 10;
            inclusive = inclusive - (c*10);
        }
        else
        {
            c = inclusive;
            d = 0;
        }
        d = inclusive;
        e = inclusive; //the variable "e" is for the decimal//
        inclusive = inclusive - a - b - c

        printNum(a);  //Printing is the variables are in the thousands, hundreds, tens or ones categories.//
        printf("Thousand ");
        printNum(b);
        printf("Hundred ");
        printNum2(c);
        printf("");
        printNum3(d);
        printf("Dollars and ... ");
        printNum4(e);
        printf("Cents\n");

    }
}

void printNum(int x)
{
    if ( x == 1)
        printf("One ");
    else if ( x == 2)
        printf("Two ");
    else if (x == 3)
        printf("Three ");
    else if (x == 4) 
        printf("Four ");
    else if (x == 5)
            printf("Five ");
    else if (x == 6)
        printf("Six ");
    else if (x == 7)
        printf("Seven ");
    else if (x == 8)
        printf("Eight ");
    else if (x == 9)
        printf("Nine ");

}
void printNum2(int x)
{
     if ( x == 10)
         printf("Ten ");
     else if ( x == 11)
         printf("Eleven ");
     else  if ( x == 12)
         printf("Twelve ");
     else if ( x == 13)
         printf("Thirteen ");
     else if (x == 14)
         printf("Fourteen ");
     else if (x == 15)
         printf("Fifteen ");
     else if (x == 16)
         printf("Sixteen ");
     else if (x == 17)
         printf("Seventeen ");
     else if (x == 18)
         printf("Eighteen ");
     else if (x == 19)
         printf("Ninteen ");
     else if (x == 2)
         printf("Twenty ");
     else if (x == 3)
         printf("Thirty ");
     else if (x == 4)
         printf("Forty ");
     else if (x == 5)
         printf("Fifty ");
     else if (x == 6)
         printf("Sixty ");
     else if (x == 7)
         printf("Seventy ");
     else if (x == 8)
         printf("Eighty ");
     else if (x == 9)
         printf("Ninety ");
}

void printNum3(int x)
{
    if ( x == 1)
        printf("One ");
    else if ( x == 2)
        printf("Two ");
    else if (x == 3)
        printf("Three ");
    else if (x == 4)
        printf("Four ");
    else if (x == 5)
        printf("Five ");
    else if (x == 6)
        printf("Six ");
    else if (x == 7)
        printf("Seven ");
    else if (x == 8)
        printf("Eight ");
    else if (x == 9)
        printf("Nine ");

}

void printNum4(int x)
{
    printf("%d, e");

}
```

Comment: Or treat the number as a string and split it at the position of the "."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the confusion between `int` and `float` and to avoid the issues with arithmaic operations between the two types, I propose

- `scan()` the input as `float`/`double`.
- Use [`sprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) to convert that as a string.
- Tokenize the string using [`strtok()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok)  based on the delimiter `.` (decimal point).
- First part (token) is integral part, use the converter function to translate.
- Second part (token) is the part representing *"cents"*. You can print it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FLOOR function (rounds to nearest integer value less than actual one), print it separately and subtract it from the original number -> then you'll have cents value which you can multiply by 100 and get their integer value.

Answer (score 0):

You are casting a float to an int implicitly. When assigning e = inclusive. That's why you get strange numbers, don't cast integers to floating point and vice versa, never !

Actually you can get the decimal part using modulo.

Maybe you can try this :

```
void printNum4(float inclusive) 
{
  //Decimal part * 100 to get cents
  float decimal = fmod(inclusive, 1) * 100;
  //Print a float with a 0 decimal precision
  printf("%.0f", decimal);
}
```