# Why does my program give me the excess output? C program

Tags: c, if-statement, generator, currency

I've made a program that is a cheque generator. Whatever amount you input in the scanf will output in words. For example if I were to to input "1234.56" My output will be "One Thousand Two Hundred Thirty Four Dollars and ... 56 Cents", or if I wanted to input the amount "0.01" the output will be "Zero Dollars and ... 1 Cents". The program works perfectly, however there is a **minor issue**, if I wanted to input the amount "9909" it will output "*Nine Thousand Nine Hundred Ninety Nine Dollars and ... 0 Cents*". The output **should** be "**Nine Thousand Nine Hundred Nine Dollars and ... 0 Cents**". Please help!

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printNum(int);
void printNum2(int);

int main()
{

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;
    int d = 0; 
    int num = 0;
    int printcents; //To convert the float "cents" to an integer.

    float inclusive;
    float cents;

    printf("Welcome to the IPC144 Cheque Generator!!\n");
    printf("PAY TO THE ORDER OF... amahmood29 (018359133)\n");
    printf("Enter a monetary value from $0.01 to $9999.99 inclusive: ");
    scanf("%f", &inclusive);

    if(inclusive < 0.00 || inclusive >= 10000.00) {
        printf("Sorry, cannot create cheque for that amount, try again next time!\n");
    }
    else
    {                                             
        a = inclusive / 1000;                          //This data is replacing our variable by diving whatever the vaulue is by either 1000, 100, 10.
        inclusive = inclusive - (a*1000);
        b = inclusive / 100; 
        inclusive = inclusive - (b*100);
        if ( inclusive > 19 ){
            c = inclusive / 10; 
            inclusive = inclusive - (c*10);
        }
        else
        {
            c = inclusive;
            d = 0;
        }
        d = inclusive;
        num = inclusive;
        cents = (inclusive - num)*100; //To calculate our "Cents" with numerals.
        printcents = cents;


        /*Printing if the variables are in the thousands, hundreds, tens or ones categories.*/
        if (c == 0 && b == 0 && a == 0){
        printf("Zero Dollars and ... %d Cents\n", printcents);
    }
    else{
        if (a > 0){ 
            printNum(a);  
            printf("Thousand ");
        }
        if (b > 0){
            printNum(b);
            printf("Hundred ");
        }
        printNum2(c);   
        if (d >= 0){
            printNum(d);
            printf("Dollars and ... ");
        }

        printf("%d", printcents);
        printf(" Cents\n");
    }
}
}
void printNum(int x)  //Created functions to easily output various if statements.
{

    if ( x == 1)
        printf("One ");
    else if ( x == 2)
        printf("Two ");
    else if (x == 3)
        printf("Three ");
    else if (x == 4) 
        printf("Four ");
    else if (x == 5)
        printf("Five ");
    else if (x == 6)
        printf("Six ");
    else if (x == 7)
        printf("Seven ");
    else if (x == 8)
        printf("Eight ");
    else if (x == 9)
        printf("Nine ");

    }

void printNum2(int x)
{
    if ( x == 10)
        printf("Ten ");
    else if ( x == 11)
        printf("Eleven ");
    else  if ( x == 12)
        printf("Twelve ");
    else if ( x == 13)
        printf("Thirteen ");
    else if (x == 14)
        printf("Fourteen ");
    else if (x == 15)
        printf("Fifteen ");
    else if (x == 16)
        printf("Sixteen ");
    else if (x == 17)
        printf("Seventeen ");
    else if (x == 18)
        printf("Eighteen ");
    else if (x == 19)
        printf("Nineteen ");
    else if (x == 2)
        printf("Twenty ");
    else if (x == 3)
        printf("Thirty ");
    else if (x == 4)
        printf("Forty ");
    else if (x == 5)
        printf("Fifty ");
    else if (x == 6)
        printf("Sixty ");
    else if (x == 7)
        printf("Seventy ");
    else if (x == 8)
        printf("Eighty ");
    else if (x == 9)
        printf("Ninety ");
}
```

I have been coding for a month now so I apologize  for the simple errors.

Comment: You've posted 5 variations on SO. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30786042/how-to-make-the-value-of-the-decimal-only-show-in-numerals). [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813698/how-to-make-my-output-show-only-whats-needed-with-my-cheque-generator-program-fo). [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814189/how-to-make-my-cheque-generator-output-exactly-what-it-is-instead-of-zero-in-c). [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814189/how-to-make-my-cheque-generator-output-exactly-what-it-is-instead-of-zero-in-c). [5]here.Suggest: Don't do that. Break problem into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you have calculated `b` and adjusted `inclusive` so it is now 9, you get to your `else` case, which sets `c` to 9 (hence the `Ninety` output) and `d` to 0, but immediately afterwards sets `d` to 9 (hence the `Nine` in the output).  I think you mixed up `c` and `d` in the `else` case.

Comment: The else case probably should just be `c = 0;` as `d` will be set just after.

Comment: @chris-dodd It works great ! However now if I try to input an amount such as 15.21 it outputs "Zero Dollars and ... 21 Cents". Help please!

Comment: @Asad Mahmood Consider not posting a 6th version of code.  Take time and figure out the remaining issues.